# Is it possible to build an Pushdown Automata for an Ambiguous Context-Free Grammar?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Say I have the following grammar:

$$S \to \epsilon \mid [S] \mid (S) \mid SS$$

This grammar is ambiguous as both the following parse trees yield the empty string

$$S \to \epsilon$$

$$S \to SS \to (S \to \epsilon) + (S \to \epsilon) = \epsilon$$

My question is basically can I still build a PDA for this language even though its ambiguous?  And if not is it ever possible to build a PDA that can recognize an ambiguous CFG or is it always impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The languages recognized by non-deterministic PDAs are precisely the context-free languages, so the answer is *yes* for them. In this case you can even do it with a deterministic PDA: essentially all you need to do is push left brackets onto the stack and pop the top of the stack when you read a right bracket, if the top of the stack is the same kind of bracket as the input.